# Unable to open logs after raname of error_log of Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I hope someone of you can help me solve a (i hope... a little) problem. I was deleting all logs processed in rotation on my server with Plesk Panel 9.0.0 and CentOS 5, in the folder "domain/statistics/logs". 
By mistake I renamed "error_log" file and now Apache can't restart. When in Putty I send the command "service httpd restart", it fails giving me the error "Unable to open logs". I just renamed the error_log file to the original but the problem remain.

I tried to access to the Plesk Panel, I went on the "Web Hosting Settings" for the specific domain, I unchecked "Custom Error Documents", applied the modidy and re-checked the option: nothing, Apache don't want to restart.

So, I have a strage situation: Apache is currently running correctly (it seems), but I can't restart it.

Please, someone can help me solve that problem? I searched in this forum and googled for a solution but... nothing...

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: What does `ls -l error_log` say? `lsattr error_log`?

Comment: Can somebody edit his question, I think on line 3, he means "can't restart", rather than can restart

Comment: Thank you for your support!

    ls - l error_log says: 
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 430475 Jan 20 04:18 error_log

    for access_log:
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24936553 Jan 20 12:40 access_log

Answer (score 1):

Qre you sure that you type the command as root ? Usualy, the openlog error is when you try to start Apache without root rights